# how to pass any class object to a stateful class in flutter(genetic type)

Tags: flutter, dart

i have several stateful classes such as income , expenses, debit, events etc and each class has its own set of attributes(int,double,string)  i have another class that i want to share among all the stateful classes because the code are similar. instead of coding a different class for income, expenses etc to do a specific task, i would like to create one class which is common among all classes

here is partial code for my common class

```
class CheckBoxAlertDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  CheckBoxAlertDialog({
    Key key,
    this.anyobjectype,
    this.database
  }) : super(key: key);

  final T anyobjectype;
  final AppDatabase database;

  @override
  CheckBoxAletDialogState createState() {
    return new CheckBoxAletDialogState();
  }
}

class CheckBoxAletDialogState extends State<CheckBoxAlertDialog> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      If(anyobjectype is type income)
          print(anyobjectype.amount)     //assume income class has type double income
      If(anyobjectype is type expense)
          print(anyobjectype.paid_amount)  //assume expense class has type double paid_amount
       If(anyobjectype is type event)
          print(anyobjectype.event_date)   //assume event class has type date event_date

       //and so on
      
   }
}
```

i want to be able to call CheckBoxAlertDialog and pass any object of class income , expenses, debit, events.  for example, i want to be able to call as follow

```
income = new income();
CheckBoxAlertDialog(anyobjectype : income, database: database,);

expense = new expense();
CheckBoxAlertDialog(anyobjectype : expense, database: database,);

debit = new debit();
CheckBoxAlertDialog(anyobjectype : debit, database: database,);
```

basically, i want to be able to pass any class object to CheckBoxAlertDialog and be able to access the class's data types in CheckBoxAlertDialog  class.  see build function in CheckBoxAlertDialog
i heard genetic data type can help but i am new to that.  can someone show me how i can pass any class object to CheckBoxAlertDialog  and be able to access the class data types in CheckBoxAlertDialog  like the example above?  thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a `InheritedWidget`. It allows your child widgets to access the members of the parent class. Check the docs at: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html

This website is also quite helpful: https://ericwindmill.com/articles/inherited_widget/